# Straight-line regression model

Tags: regression, model

Why the writer use the minus the average of x in the x matrix?

[image: matrix form]

Comment: That will give for example $y_n=\gamma_0 + \gamma_1(x_n-\bar x) +\varepsilon_n$.  If you compare it to $y_n=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_n +\varepsilon_n$ then you would get $\beta_1=\gamma_1$ and $\beta_0 = \gamma_0 - \gamma_1 \bar x$, so the issue is whether the intercept is measured at $x=0$ or $x=\bar x$.  Remember that the OLS regression line passes through the mean of the data

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. :) So we have two notations of one thing and it depends on your problem. Please give me a link to study more if it is possible. also for OLS.

Comment: @Henry maybe convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

*As requested in comments:*

That will give for example $y_n=\gamma_0 + \gamma_1(x_n-\bar x) +\varepsilon_n$.

If you compare it to $y_n=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_n +\varepsilon_n$ then you would get $\beta_1=\gamma_1$ and $\beta_0=\gamma_0 - \gamma_1 \bar x$,

so the issue is whether the intercept is measured at $x=0$ or $x=\bar x$.

Remember that the OLS regression line passes through the mean of the data.